# Error while configuring Sql server 2005 for full text search

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to index a table for full text search in a SQL server 2005.

When I select the change tracking as Automatic and click on the next button, I get the following error

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server
>
> This wizard will close because it
>   encountered the following error:
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server+Management+Studio&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardFrameworkErrorSR&EvtID=UncaughtException&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this
>   request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the object 'sp_help_category',
>   database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. The
>   SELECT permission was denied on the
>   object 'sysjobs_view', database
>   'msdb', schema 'dbo'. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 229)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4035&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=229&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: Is the windows service account responsible for managing the Full Text catalog (including index searching and building) running under a domain or local account that doesn't have the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I got the problem, I used to login using sql authentication.
One has to login using windows authentication, to have the required permissions.

Its gonna be a problem, I guess, when I configure the sql server 2005 for full text search of my hosting provider. Because the only way I have access to that database is via sql authentication.

Comment: you can explicitly grant permissions to the SQL Authenticated user with sufficient permissions to perform the actions you were trying to do. Granting them DBO would work, but it's a really bad idea. I'd recommend granting them db_datareader and db_datawriter, then on every required stored procedure, grant that user execute permissions on that SP (rather than granting them execute on the database, as that can be just as dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user trying to do the updates (as Kane said, perhaps a service account, or you) doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform that operation. It looks like the user needs to be generally elevated, or granted specific rights for those two objects.

Comment: How can I get those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the necessary permission to configure fulltext from SSMS. Ask an administrator to give you the necessary privileges, or ask the administrator to configure the fulltext for you.

Comment: The database is on my vista PC, I opened the sql sever management studio as administrator and logged into it using sql authentication.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You still don't have the necessary privilege, the message is more than clear about that. If you are the administrator, then you must grant those privileges to the account you use to do the operation.